# Jquery Bar graph to load dynamically and get tool tip

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bar-chart

I am searching online but not able to get a plugin which can meet my requirements.

I make an AJAX call and get back an three arrays. Say for example:

```
 Name[0] = "ravi"
 Name[1] = "john"
 Name[2] = "robert"

 Expense[0] = "100$"
 Expense[1] = "50$"
 Expense[2] = "120$"

 Comment[0] = "You are Spending Properly"
 Comment[1] = "You can spend more"
 Comment[2] = " you are spening too much"
```

Now with `Name` on y-axis and expense on x-axis I am able to get bar graph using many plugins. My problem is when some one hovers on any of the bars the respective commment should appear. The max I am able to show in the tool tip is the combination of name and expense. Is there any plug in which supports this feature where I can add comment as the tooltip.

Answer (score 1):

You can use powerTip.   You might need to make changes to your js.  But this will be helpful.  Follow the steps mentioned here : [jquery powertip](http://stevenbenner.github.com/jquery-powertip/)